# How do I debug a form which does not send an email?

Tags: kohana

I have a form build from the kohana framework which should send  an email.

when I press the "send" button, everything seems to work fine...no error messages...but no email turns up!

If I can´t see anything in firebug..where can I look?

the application logs state

> "error: Missing i18n entry contact.captcha.valid for language en_US"

but I don´t know how to get to the bottom of the problem..any help welcome..
yours,

Rob

Ill try and find out which version im using.....the application is the latest version of Ushahidi (2.2.1) www.ushahidi.com

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') OR die('No direct access allowed.');
```

/**
 * Captcha library.
 *
 * $Id: Captcha.php 3917 2009-01-21 03:06:22Z zombor $
 *
 * @package    Captcha
 * @author     Kohana Team
 * @copyright  (c) 2007-2008 Kohana Team
 * @license    http://kohanaphp.com/license.html
 */
class Captcha_Core {

```
// Captcha singleton
protected static $instance;

// Style-dependent Captcha driver
protected $driver;

// Config values
public static $config = array
(
    'style'      => 'basic',
    'width'      => 150,
    'height'     => 50,
    'complexity' => 4,
    'background' => '',
    'fontpath'   => '',
    'fonts'      => array(),
    'promote'    => FALSE,
);

/**
 * Singleton instance of Captcha.
 *
 * @return  object
 */
public static function instance()
{
    // Create the instance if it does not exist
    empty(self::$instance) and new Captcha;

    return self::$instance;
}

/**
 * Constructs and returns a new Captcha object.
 *
 * @param   string  config group name
 * @return  object
 */
public static function factory($group = NULL)
{
    return new Captcha($group);
}

/**
 * Constructs a new Captcha object.
 *
 * @throws  Kohana_Exception
 * @param   string  config group name
 * @return  void
 */
public function __construct($group = NULL)
{
    // Create a singleton instance once
    empty(self::$instance) and self::$instance = $this;

    // No config group name given
    if ( ! is_string($group))
    {
        $group = 'default';
    }

    // Load and validate config group
    if ( ! is_array($config = Kohana::config('captcha.'.$group)))
        throw new Kohana_Exception('captcha.undefined_group', $group);

    // All captcha config groups inherit default config group
    if ($group !== 'default')
    {
        // Load and validate default config group
        if ( ! is_array($default = Kohana::config('captcha.default')))
            throw new Kohana_Exception('captcha.undefined_group', 'default');

        // Merge config group with default config group
        $config += $default;
    }

    // Assign config values to the object
    foreach ($config as $key => $value)
    {
        if (array_key_exists($key, self::$config))
        {
            self::$config[$key] = $value;
        }
    }

    // Store the config group name as well, so the drivers can access it
    self::$config['group'] = $group;

    // If using a background image, check if it exists
    if ( ! empty($config['background']))
    {
        self::$config['background'] = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($config['background']));

        if ( ! is_file(self::$config['background']))
            throw new Kohana_Exception('captcha.file_not_found', self::$config['background']);
    }

    // If using any fonts, check if they exist
    if ( ! empty($config['fonts']))
    {
        self::$config['fontpath'] = str_replace('\\', '/', realpath($config['fontpath'])).'/';

        foreach ($config['fonts'] as $font)
        {
            if ( ! is_file(self::$config['fontpath'].$font))
                throw new Kohana_Exception('captcha.file_not_found', self::$config['fontpath'].$font);
        }
    }

    // Set driver name
    $driver = 'Captcha_'.ucfirst($config['style']).'_Driver';

    // Load the driver
    if ( ! Kohana::auto_load($driver))
        throw new Kohana_Exception('core.driver_not_found', $config['style'], get_class($this));

    // Initialize the driver
    $this->driver = new $driver;

    // Validate the driver
    if ( ! ($this->driver instanceof Captcha_Driver))
        throw new Kohana_Exception('core.driver_implements', $config['style'], get_class($this), 'Captcha_Driver');

    Kohana::log('debug', 'Captcha Library initialized');
}

/**
 * Validates a Captcha response and updates response counter.
 *
 * @param   string   captcha response
 * @return  boolean
 */
public static function valid($response)
{
    // Maximum one count per page load
    static $counted;

    // User has been promoted, always TRUE and don't count anymore
    if (self::instance()->promoted())
        return TRUE;

    // Challenge result
    $result = (bool) self::instance()->driver->valid($response);

    // Increment response counter
    if ($counted !== TRUE)
    {
        $counted = TRUE;

        // Valid response
        if ($result === TRUE)
        {
            self::instance()->valid_count(Session::instance()->get('captcha_valid_count') + 1);
        }
        // Invalid response
        else
        {
            self::instance()->invalid_count(Session::instance()->get('captcha_invalid_count') + 1);
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

/**
 * Gets or sets the number of valid Captcha responses for this session.
 *
 * @param   integer  new counter value
 * @param   boolean  trigger invalid counter (for internal use only)
 * @return  integer  counter value
 */
public function valid_count($new_count = NULL, $invalid = FALSE)
{
    // Pick the right session to use
    $session = ($invalid === TRUE) ? 'captcha_invalid_count' : 'captcha_valid_count';

    // Update counter
    if ($new_count !== NULL)
    {
        $new_count = (int) $new_count;

        // Reset counter = delete session
        if ($new_count < 1)
        {
            Session::instance()->delete($session);
        }
        // Set counter to new value
        else
        {
            Session::instance()->set($session, (int) $new_count);
        }

        // Return new count
        return (int) $new_count;
    }

    // Return current count
    return (int) Session::instance()->get($session);
}

/**
 * Gets or sets the number of invalid Captcha responses for this session.
 *
 * @param   integer  new counter value
 * @return  integer  counter value
 */
public function invalid_count($new_count = NULL)
{
    return $this->valid_count($new_count, TRUE);
}

/**
 * Resets the Captcha response counters and removes the count sessions.
 *
 * @return  void
 */
public function reset_count()
{
    $this->valid_count(0);
    $this->valid_count(0, TRUE);
}

/**
 * Checks whether user has been promoted after having given enough valid responses.
 *
 * @param   integer  valid response count threshold
 * @return  boolean
 */
public function promoted($threshold = NULL)
{
    // Promotion has been disabled
    if (self::$config['promote'] === FALSE)
        return FALSE;

    // Use the config threshold
    if ($threshold === NULL)
    {
        $threshold = self::$config['promote'];
    }

    // Compare the valid response count to the threshold
    return ($this->valid_count() >= $threshold);
}

/**
 * Returns or outputs the Captcha challenge.
 *
 * @param   boolean  TRUE to output html, e.g. <img src="#" />
 * @return  mixed    html string or void
 */
public function render($html = TRUE)
{
    return $this->driver->render($html);
}

/**
 * Magically outputs the Captcha challenge.
 *
 * @return  mixed
 */
public function __toString()
{
    return $this->render();
}
```

} // End Captcha Class

Comment: looks like you have a captcha reference in you form that is nowhere to be found. Can you post your code?

Comment: Could you add some details like: What version of Kohana are you using?, What do you use to send emails?, What do you for captcha and how?

Comment: I´m not too sure where to look. The framework is kohana and there is a php file called "Captcha.php"

Comment: You have posted the code of the Captcha library included in Kohana 2. - http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/captcha

But that's not really helping. Could you find and post the code which process the form when it's posted?

Answer (score 0):

From the little details provided I think your site uses the I18n library from Kohana for internationalization of the site. The other option is your site use Kohana messages for showing form errors.

The Validation class uses the __() function internally when generation validation errors. I think you don't have a message for key `valid` specified in `APPPATH/messages/contact/captcha.php`.

You should try to investigate more on how the form is processed and whether some validation errors are being generated. There might be an error in the captcha validation and despite it seem there is no error, there might be and just the error message could not be shown.

Comment: This is in the core - $Id: Kohana.php 3917 2009-01-21 03:06:22Z zombor $...I think this is the version number

Answer (score 0):

```
class Contact_Controller extends Main_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {

        $this->template->header->this_page = 'contact';
        $this->template->content = new View('contact');

        $this->template->header->page_title .= Kohana::lang('ui_main.contact').Kohana::config('settings.title_delimiter');

        // Setup and initialize form field names
        $form = array (
            'contact_name' => '',
            'contact_email' => '',
            'contact_phone' => '',
            'contact_subject' => '',
            'contact_message' => '',
            'captcha' => ''
        );

        // Copy the form as errors, so the errors will be stored with keys
        // corresponding to the form field names
        $captcha = Captcha::factory();
        $errors = $form;
        $form_error = FALSE;
        $form_sent = FALSE;

        // Check, has the form been submitted, if so, setup validation
        if ($_POST)
        {
            // Instantiate Validation, use $post, so we don't overwrite $_POST fields with our own things
            $post = Validation::factory($_POST);

            // Add some filters
            $post->pre_filter('trim', TRUE);

            // Add some rules, the input field, followed by a list of checks, carried out in order
            $post->add_rules('contact_name', 'required', 'length[3,100]');
            $post->add_rules('contact_email', 'required','email', 'length[4,100]');
            $post->add_rules('contact_subject', 'required', 'length[3,100]');
            $post->add_rules('contact_message', 'required');
            $post->add_rules('captcha', 'required', 'Captcha::valid');

            // Test to see if things passed the rule checks
            if ($post->validate())
            {
                // Yes! everything is valid - Send email
                $site_email = Kohana::config('settings.site_email');
                $message = Kohana::lang('ui_admin.sender').": " . $post->contact_name . "\n";
                $message .= Kohana::lang('ui_admin.email').": " . $post->contact_email . "\n";
                $message .= Kohana::lang('ui_admin.phone').": " . $post->contact_phone . "\n\n";
                $message .= Kohana::lang('ui_admin.message').": \n" . $post->contact_message . "\n\n\n";
                $message .= "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\n";
                $message .= Kohana::lang('ui_admin.sent_from_website'). url::base();

                // Send Admin Message
                email::send( $site_email, $post->contact_email, $post->contact_subject, $message, FALSE );

                $form_sent = TRUE;
            }
            // No! We have validation errors, we need to show the form again, with the errors
            else
            {
                // repopulate the form fields
                $form = arr::overwrite($form, $post->as_array());

                // populate the error fields, if any
                $errors = arr::overwrite($errors, $post->errors('contact'));
                $form_error = TRUE;
            }
        }

        $this->template->content->form = $form;
        $this->template->content->errors = $errors;
        $this->template->content->form_error = $form_error;
        $this->template->content->form_sent = $form_sent;
        $this->template->content->captcha = $captcha;

        // Rebuild Header Block
        $this->template->header->header_block = $this->themes->header_block();
        $this->template->footer->footer_block = $this->themes->footer_block();
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit your question with this info and delete this non-answer

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been solved!

My Email server was not set up properly. I resolved the postfix issue and now the comments form is working as it should,

thanks to all who answered,

Rob